# pcp_recovery_node command hangs while recovering standby

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, high-availability, postgresql-10, pgpool

Its a sub-part of [cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54999672/multiple-postgres-clusters-not-instances-on-2-machines) , I am building. When I am executing pcp_recovery_node on master to build standby from scratch with the command

> pcp_recovery_node -h 193.185.83.119 -p 9898 -U postgres -n 1

Here, 193.185.83.119 is vip. 
It successfully builds and starts the standby on node-b ( say nodes are node-a and node-b) but at the same time above command does not return and simply hangs in shell like :-

> [postgres@rollc-filesrvr1 data]$ pcp_recovery_node -h 193.185.83.119 -p 9898 -U postgres -n 1
>   Password:

I have to use ctrl+c to come out of this session. 
Later on when I try to create a test db on node-a (master) i get following error :

> ```
>       postgres=# create database test;
>         ERROR:  source database "template1" is being accessed by other users
>         DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.
> ```

I confirm that pgpool.service is running at the time of running this command on node-a and i have tried using on/off pgpool.service on node-b (standby) before issuing pcp command. Result remains the same.

Also I tried googling and tweaked following settings in pgpool.conf . I am not sure if it could be something with these parameters:

> wd_lifecheck_dbname in pgpool.conf

Initially related settings to above were ( and i was getting still same result):

```
wd_lifecheck_dbname = 'template1'
wd_lifecheck_user = 'nobody'
wd_lifecheck_password = ''
```

later on , i found different settings at [here](https://www.pgpool.net/mantisbt/view.php?id=242), [here](https://www.pgpool.net/mantisbt/view.php?id=394) and one suggestion at [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/pgpool-general@pgfoundry.org/msg01639.html) and tried different combinations like following :

```
wd_lifecheck_dbname = 'template1'
wd_lifecheck_user = 'postgres'
wd_lifecheck_password = ''
```

or

```
wd_lifecheck_dbname = 'postgres'
wd_lifecheck_user = 'postgres'
wd_lifecheck_password = ''
```

But none helped in changing the situation neither on shell nor allowed me to create test db on master. I feel , i reached a dead end.

I am still not able to fully understand the purpose and meaning of above 3 parameters in pgpool and somehow suspect that these are the ones I am not configuration correct although there could be others reasons also.

just to help , here is the environment details again.

- node-a and nod-b environment : rhel 7.6
- postgres version : 10.7
- pgpool-|| version: 4.0.3
- replication slot + wal archive

Here are the logs from node-a pgpool.service

```
Mar 18 21:10:17 node-a pgpool[16583]: 2019-03-18 21:10:17: pid 16642: LOG:  forked new pcp worker, pid=8534 socket=7
Mar 18 21:10:17 node-a pgpool[16583]: 2019-03-18 21:10:17: pid 8534: LOG:  starting recovering node 1
Mar 18 21:10:17 node-a pgpool[16583]: 2019-03-18 21:10:17: pid 8534: LOG:  executing recovery
Mar 18 21:10:17 node-a pgpool[16583]: 2019-03-18 21:10:17: pid 8534: DETAIL:  starting recovery command: "SELECT pgpool_recovery('recovery_1st_stage', 'node-a-ip', '/data/test/data', '5438', 1)"
Mar 18 21:10:17 node-a pgpool[16583]: 2019-03-18 21:10:17: pid 8534: LOG:  executing recovery
Mar 18 21:10:17 node-a pgpool[16583]: 2019-03-18 21:10:17: pid 8534: DETAIL:  disabling statement_timeout
Mar 18 21:10:18 node-a pgpool[16583]: 2019-03-18 21:10:18: pid 8534: LOG:  node recovery, 1st stage is done
Mar 18 21:11:37 node-a pgpool[16583]: 2019-03-18 21:11:37: pid 8534: LOG:  checking if postmaster is started
Mar 18 21:11:37 node-a pgpool[16583]: 2019-03-18 21:11:37: pid 8534: DETAIL:  trying to connect to postmaster on hostname:node-b-ip database:postgres user:postgres (retry 0 times)
...
...2 more times 
Mar 18 21:11:49 node-a pgpool[16583]: 2019-03-18 21:11:49: pid 8534: LOG:  checking if postmaster is started
Mar 18 21:11:49 node-a pgpool[16583]: 2019-03-18 21:11:49: pid 8534: DETAIL:  trying to connect to postmaster on hostname:node-a-ip database:template1 user:postgres (retry 0 times)
...it keeps on trying till i press ctrl+c on pcp command windows . I have seen it going upto 30 or more.
```

Also node-b is never being shown as up while checking with pgpool.

> postgres=> show pool_nodes;
>    node_id |    hostname    | port | status | lb_weight |  role   | select_cnt | load_balance_node | replication_delay | last_status_change
>   ---------+----------------+------+--------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------
>    0       | node-a-ip      | 5438 | up     | 0.500000  | primary | 0          | true              | 0                 | 2019-03-18 22:59:19
>    1       | node-b-ip      | 5438 | **down**   | 0.500000  | standby | 0          | false             | 0                 | 2019-03-18 22:59:19
>   (2 rows)

**EDIT** Now i am at least being able to correct the last part of this query. i.e. adding the standby node to cluster:

> [postgres@node-a-hostname]$ pcp_attach_node -n 1
>   Password:
>   pcp_attach_node -- Command Successful

and now the last part is at least showing correct situation:

> postgres=> show pool_nodes;
>    node_id |    hostname    | port | status | lb_weight |  role   | select_cnt | load_balance_node | replication_delay | last_status_change
>   ---------+----------------+------+--------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------
>    0       | node-a-ip | 5438 | up     | 0.500000  | primary | 0          | false             | 0                 | 2019-03-18 22:59:19
>    1       | node-b-ip | 5438 | **up**     | 0.500000  | standby | 0          | true              | 0                 | 2019-03-19 11:38:38
>   (2 rows)

But underlying problem of not able to create db on node1 is still there:

**EDIT2:** I tried insert and update on master and they are correctly being replicated to node2 but create db is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First correction to EDIT1: Indeed pcp_attach_node helped correcting the output of show pool_nodes but it further complicated the issue as the other commands

> pcp_watchdog_info -h 193.185.83.119 -p 9898 -U postgres

started getting stuck. Later on , I found out

> pcp_attach_node -n 1

was not needed at all to attach standby or correcting the output of show pool_nodes; on master **IF** original pcp_recovery_node completes correctly.

Well, Root cause of original problem , and watchdog getting stuck originated out of it later on , was that pgpool_remote_start script was not completing correctly even after starting standby. I could see it in

> ps -ef | grep pgpool

on master.

I contacted pgpool_bug_tracking system at [here](https://www.pgpool.net/mantisbt/view.php?id=475#bugnotes) and they helped me further fixing it.
It was incorrect postgres start command in pgpool_remote_start which was causing troubles and hence pcp_recover_node was not completing and no other later on.

Correct command in pgpool_remote_start should be something like( and I used it):

```
ssh -T postgres@$REMOTE_HOST /usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_ctl -w start -D /data/test/data 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null </dev/null &
```

while i was using

> ssh -T postgres@$REMOTE_HOST /usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_ctl start -D /data/test/data

I was missing -w flag.
Also there was no redirection of stdout and stderr to /dev/null and missing EOF signal sending to it.

One still unclear to me but helpful to someone facing similar problem: First start pgpool.service on standby or keep it running before issuing pcp command on master.

Comment: One more insight, I did not change any of those wd_lifecheck_dbname in this process and they are still as per my last attempt : wd_lifecheck_dbname = 'postgres', wd_lifecheck_user = 'postgres' and wd_lifecheck_password = 'postgres' and only changing pgpool_remote_start command helped fixing my problem.